# How do I get Mail.app to not send mail in offline mode?

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

I want to review my mail before it's sent out using Mail.app 4.4

In order to do that, I take all my accounts offline, but I noticed that my mail is still sent right away because I've got an active internet connection.

Is there a way to have my outgoing mail sit in an Outbox so I can take a look at it before I'm ready to blast them all out?

This account is using a corporate Google Apps account (Gmail) with the standard IMAP/SMTP setup.

(Ideally, I’d like to keep my internet connection on – I know that unplugging my machine is one solution to this, but I need to also be able to access the web to answer mail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save a draft of a message without sending it, just hit Save, not Send. It'll be saved in your Drafts folder instead of your Outbox. Then you can review your drafts later, and choose to send, continue editing, or delete.

Comment: Hmm… this is pretty close, but part of why I want to disconnect is to mitigate the flood of mail that comes in. I'd rather just not see it until I'm ready to work on it.

Comment: @Edward Saving to your (local, not IMAP) Drafts folder doesn't keep you from being able to disconnect.

Comment: Yeah - I wish I could disconnect and email would just drop into my Outbox, waiting to be sent out when I connect next, but this is a valid answer. Thanks!